# AWS Lambda costs at resource level granularity

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cost-explorer

Does AWS Cost explorer provide resource-level granularity for Lambda functions?

Comment: What do you mean by "resource-level granularity"? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, I mean per lambda function cost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything direct given by AWS.

But you can write a cloud-watch insights query on the lambda logs, and calculate the gb-secs, and get the approximate cost by multiplying with the pricing rates.

Answer (score 0):

It does not, you can't filter down to the resource level here:

[image: Screenshot from cost explorer]